# How to make a 3-tier app on a single server that would be easy to distribute to multiple machines

Tags: php, rest, distributed, 3-tier

I am curious about what would be the best way to create a 3-tier application that is supposed to work on separate servers on the same cluster, that works on the same server.

Would using REST to connect representation tier to logic tier, as well as connect to DB both running on localhost? Are there any frameworks for this?

Comment: Since REST is just a style, bunch of recommendations about how to write applications' interfaces - there isn't any ready-to-use implementation. You have to read about it and start following the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Kohana framework](http://kohanaframework.org) to do this. It has an excellent request execution mechanism where you can make external requests from inside your application.